# Tabindex not using correct order after selecting an element that becomes hidden

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[JSBin here](https://jsbin.com/tihayad/edit?html,js,output)

[Standalone](https://output.jsbin.com/tihayad)

I have 3 inputs with `tabindex` 1, 2, and 3.  If I place my cursor in the first (Search) box and tab, everything proceeds as normal.

However, if I select one of the overlay/dropdown elements that appears when I mouse into the Search box and then hit tab I am moved to the third tabindex input.

One thing I've noticed is that the `document.activeElement` becomes the `body` element after I select an item in the dropdown.  Even still, I don't understand why it would move to the third element instead of the next in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `tabindex="1"` to the inner div also ([Standalone](https://output.jsbin.com/bukolayuhe/1)):

```
var app = angular.module('binner', []);

app

.controller('MainCtrl', function() {

})


.directive('picker', function($document, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template: 
          ['<input tabindex="1" ng-model="picker.current.name" ng-focus="picker.open($event)" required="required" ng-model="picker.searchText" ng-model-options="{debounce: 333}" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" />',
           '<div ng-show="picker.isOpen" class="overlay">',
               '<div tabindex="1" ng-click="picker.chooseItem(i)" ng-repeat="i in picker.items">{{i.name}}</div>',
           '</div>'].join(''),
        controller: PickerCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'picker',
        link: pickerLink,
    };

    function pickerLink(scope, iEl) {
        var picker = scope.picker;

        picker.open = openDropdown;
        picker.close = closeDropdown;

        //////////////////////////////////////////

        function openDropdown() {
            $document.bind('click', closeDropdown);
            picker.isOpen = true;
        }

        function closeDropdown(e) {
            if(e === undefined || !iEl[0].contains(e.target)) {
                $document.unbind('click', closeDropdown);
                picker.isOpen = false;

                if(!$rootScope.$$phase) {
                    scope.$digest();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});


function PickerCtrl() {
    this.items = [{name: 'first'}, {name: 'second'}, {name: 'third'}];

    this.chooseItem = function(item) {
      this.current = item;

      this.close();
    };
}
```

https://jsbin.com/bukolayuhe/1/edit?html,js,output